# hide menu on wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I need to hide my menu on the home page and make it appear when scrolling down. I am using Wordpress and Elementor. I was able to achieve this by installing "Custom CSS & JS" plug-ins which let me add any JS code I need.

I added this code on my menu section using elementor custom CSS:

```css
@media (min-width: 1024px){
#menu {
    display:none;   
    width:100%!important;
}
}
```

and then I added this Java Script, to my website using the plug in that I installed,

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      
      if ( $ (window).width() > 1024) {
       
        if ( $ (window).scrollTop() >= 400) {
            $ ('#menu').fadeIn();
          } else {
            $ ('#menu').fadeOut();
             }
      }
    });
});
```

which did the job, but now the menu is hidden on all the pages on the website and it appears when I scroll down. I want it to do that just on the home page. I tried to add an IF command, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The body element of the home site of your wordpress site should have a class of `home`. You can use the inspector of your browser (right click, inspect) to see which classes are applied to the body or wrapper classes within it.

So you can target the menu element in your css and js using this class:
`.home #menu { ... }`

The css styles (you have the display none) will only be applied if the menu is inside of the parent element with specific class.

Comment: where should i add this? since when I added it at the beginning it just disappeared, my website is this: https://mangoandlatch.com/ you can check it since my home page is just the link without a HOME

Comment: To style.css of your theme, or custom css in the theme customizer of your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enclose that within a conditional that tests with `window.location.href`  as such?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if(window.location.href === "https://mangoandlatch.com/") {
          if ( $ (window).width() > 1024) {
           
        if ( $ (window).scrollTop() >= 400) {
            $ ('#menu').fadeIn();
          } else {
            $ ('#menu').fadeOut();
             }
          }
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: that made it work on all the pages and totally disappear on the home page, I want the opposite. I want the function to apply only on the home page "https://mangoandlatch.com/" and always show on the other pages.

Comment: @Elie hey sorry about that I just noticed that I had made a typo on the conditional statement. Now it should work the way you expect just copy the code and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: As you can see the new conditional only runs `if(window.location.href === "https://mangoandlatch.com/")` . Corrected the initial response so it should work now

Comment: well now the effect worked on the home page but on the other pages it just disappeared, for somehow reasons and I believe its because of the CSS code that I added. I tried to remove it nothing changed